# gpg - Backing up private keys

Tags: gnupg

Having created my keys using

```
gpg --full-generate-key
```

I want to export the keys for back-up, and to install them on other machines I use.

So, I use

```
gpg -a --export KeyName >KeyName.pub
```

and

```
gpg -a --export-secret-keys KeyName >KeyName
```

to export the public and private components of the keys I've generated, and

```
gpg --export-ownertrust >ownertrust.txt
```

to export the trust database.

I think this gives me everything I need to re-install/re-configure on a second machine, but it does leave me with some questions:

1. All the public key information is also stored in the private key export, so the first export is redundent? Is there any reason to just export the public key like this?
2. The second export, the export of the private key, is still enciphered using the pass-phrase I used during key generation? There are StackExchange answers saying that the private key is both enciphered, and that it is not. The gnuPG online doc's state "Note that exporting a secret key can be a security risk if the exported keys are sent over an insecure channel." that implies the exported key is un-enciphered???
3. Should the revocation certificates that are created by the key generation be retained? I'm not sure of the utility of them, unless it is to print them as QR codes to give to people I trust in case I go under a bus tomorrow...

Is there anything else I should be backing-up? And assuming the private key export is enciphered, what are the security risks of someone obtaining the exported file, without the pass-phrase?

Andy.